# Questions from Silverman's Complex Analysisv about Conformal Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

1. Prove that the mapping $w=f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \hspace{0.5cm} (c\neq 0, ad-bc\neq 0)$ is conformal at the point $\delta =-d/c$  i.e., that it
   carries any two curves $C$ and $C^*$ in the $z$-plane forming an angle of $\alpha$ radians with its vertex at $\delta$ into two curves $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma^*$ in the $w$-plane forming an angle of $\alpha$ radians with its vertex at infinity.
2. Prove that the mapping $w=f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \hspace{0.5cm} (c\neq 0, ad-bc\neq 0)$ is conformal at infinity, i.e., that it carries any
   two curves $C$ and $C^*$ in the $z$-plane forming an angle of $\alpha$ radians with its vertex at infinity into two curves $\Gamma$ and T* in the w-plane forming an angle
   of a radians with its vertex at A =
   a/c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part $1$: False. Note that $$w’ = \frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2}$$ exists for all $z$ except $z \neq - \dfrac{d}{c}$, we observe that the bilinear transformation is conformal, everywhere **except at $z =-\dfrac{d}{c}$**, a point at which $w$ is also not defined.

---

Part $2$: Note that on substitution $z = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$, we get: $$w = \frac{a+b\epsilon}{c + d\epsilon} = f(\epsilon)$$ Now, $$f’(\epsilon) = \frac{bc-ad}{(c+d\epsilon)^2}$$ Now, $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \,\,f’(\epsilon) = \frac{bc-ad}{c^2}\neq 0$$

Hence, the bilinear transformation is conformal at $z = \infty$.